# Why aren't the items in a Picker (Xamarin.Forms) updated after raising PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I've set up a `Picker` so that each item is shown with a random number appended to it (via a converter). I've also added a button that raises the `PropertyChanged` event on the list, so that the items are shown with a new set of random numbers. However, even though the `PropertyChanged` event is being raised, the items don't appear to be updated.

Here's the XAML layout with the `Picker` and `Button`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Picker
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
        />
    <Button
        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        Text="Refresh"
        />
</StackLayout>
```

Here's the view model, which contains `MyList` and `RefreshCommand`. The `RefreshCommand` raises the `PropertyChanged` event for `MyList` (via `ViewModelBase`, which is part of the MVVM Light Toolkit):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyEnum> _myList;
    public ObservableCollection<MyEnum> MyList
    {
        get => _myList;
        set => Set(ref _myList, value);
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand =>
        new RelayCommand(() => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MyList)));
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    One, Two, Three, Four, Five
}
```

Here's the converter, which appends a random number to the given value:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return $"{value} {random.Next(100)}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Things work when the page is first displayed: each item in `MyList` is shown with a random number appended to it. However, when I click on the Refresh button, which raises the `PropertyChanged` event for `MyList` (I verified this), the items in the `Picker` are not re-evaluated. I expected new random numbers to show up but it's the same numbers as before (in other words, nothing happens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the Picker's items source like:

```
RefreshCommand = new Command( async () =>
{
    ObservableCollection<MyEnum> list = MyList;
    MyList = null;
    await Task.Delay(10);
    MyList = list;
});
```

It will trigger the converter again to refreh the random value.

Comment: This works, thanks. But I feel it's a bit of a hack. I believe that the `Picker` should do the right thing and refresh when `PropertyChanged` is raised on the data-bound list. As a side note, I had to do a similar thing to keep the `SelectedItem` (not shown in the original question) because it's lost after setting `MyList` to `null`.